# The method setMessage(String) is undefined for the type Dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a dialog, but I don't know how to edit the message.

```
Dialog d2 = new Dialog(this);
d2.setTitle("title ok");
d2.setMessage("error here");
d2.show();
```

What function should I use?
Thanks a lot `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Builder inner class, for what you are doing you probably want an AlertDialog so make a new AlertDialog.Builder

```
  b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  b.setMessage(...);
  ...
  b.build().show()
```